# Dialogflow with Botium-cli using mochawesome : undefined Buttons

Tags: chatbot, botium-box, mochawesome

Button is working in bot replies but in mochawesome #bot reply is undefined

sample convo
#bot
BUTTON Pin Mailer

#me
Pin Mailer

#bot
BUTTONS Pick up|Back to menu

#me
Pick up

but in mochawesome bot response undefined
I’m using

> botium-cli run mochawesome.

[screenshot mochawesome Conversation Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWHn8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the mochawesome reporter in Botium CLI works with text messages only.

See [Github repository](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-cli/blob/master/src/run/index.js):

```
  ...
  const messageLog = []
  const attachmentsLog = []
  const listenerMe = (container, msg) => {
    messageLog.push('#me: ' + msg.messageText)
    if (msg.attachments) attachmentsLog.push(...msg.attachments)
  }
  const listenerBot = (container, msg) => {
    messageLog.push('#bot: ' + msg.messageText)
    if (msg.attachments) attachmentsLog.push(...msg.attachments)
  }
  const listenerAttachments = (container, attachment) => {
    attachmentsLog.push(attachment)
  }
  driver.on('MESSAGE_SENTTOBOT', listenerMe)
  driver.on('MESSAGE_RECEIVEDFROMBOT', listenerBot)
  driver.on('MESSAGE_ATTACHMENT', listenerAttachments)
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Florian Treml

Comment: Hi, latest botium-cli (0.0.72) shows message attachments like buttons, cards, pictures in the transcript as well